# After upgrade to Nougat phone started forgetting recent apps

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

After my S7 Edge upgraded to Nougat, I noticed it only keeps a few apps in Recent Apps list, as opposed to before when it kept basically everything until I removed it. The amount of apps in the list changes over time, so maybe it only shows apps opened in last X hours, but I am not sure. I haven't been able to find anything relevant in Settings. The phone isn't rooted and isn't in Developer mode.

The strange thing is that I haven't seen anybody else mentioning this issue. *Does* it happen for anybody else? And any idea how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a feature, not a bug. http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/05/18/android-n-includes-tweak-of-recent-apps-ui-with-clear-all-button-at-top-only-7-apps-included-in-switcher-and-quick-switch-shortcut/

The article says that Google claims that "their user research showed that over 99% of users never accessed an app further back than 7 in the recent apps UI".

Unfortunately, for the thousands of 1%ers, this is an annoying change! I have yet to find a setting to modify it's behaviour, and it's possible that it's simply not configurable.